# Ruby Regular Expression: Setting $1 variable in a hash

Tags: ruby, regex

Everything in this code works properly, except the contents of the `$1` variable aren't being properly displayed. According to my tests, all the matching is being done properly, I am just having trouble figuring out how to actually output the contents of `$1`.

```
  codeTags = {
              /\[b\](.+?)\[\/b\]/m => "<strong>#{$1}</strong>",
              /\[i\](.+?)\[\/i\]/m => "<em>#{$1}</em>"
             }

             regexp = Regexp.new(/(#{Regexp.union(codeTags.keys)})/)
             message = (message).gsub(/#{regexp}/) do |match|
               codeTags[codeTags.keys.select {|k| match =~ Regexp.new(k)}[0]]
             end

  return message.html_safe
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can debug with tap like, `"<strong>#{ $1.tap { |x| p x } }</strong>". If the value of x is nil, then there were no matches. You'll need to inspect your regex in that case. Can you let us know.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am using Ruby 1.8.7, so do not have the Object#tap method available to me. However, I did test that there is a match by changing the "gsub" block to `codeTags[codeTags.keys.select {|k| match =~ Regexp.new(k)}[0]]+$1`. The `$1` properly printed the value between [b][/b].

Comment: So what you are trying to do here is replace bold with strong and italics with emphasis tags ? Btw [tap is available for 1.8.7](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/classes/Object.html#M000045).

Comment: Oh, I read that it was new in 1.9. Yes, that's what I'm trying do. See my comment on mu's post below to see why I'm using this method instead of using a bunch of gsub's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as you do this:

```
codeTags = {
    /\[b\](.+?)\[\/b\]/m => "<strong>#{$1}</strong>",
    /\[i\](.+?)\[\/i\]/m => "<em>#{$1}</em>"
}
```

The `#{$1}` bits in the values are interpolated using whatever happens to be in `$1` at the time. The values will most likely be `"<strong></strong>"` and `"<em></em>"` and those aren't very useful.

And `regexp` is already a regular expression object so `gsub(/#{regexp}/)` should be just `gsub(regexp)`. Similar things apply to the keys of `codeTags`, they're already regular expression objects so you don't need to `Regexp.new(k)`.

I'd change the whole structure, you're overcomplicating things. Just something simple like this would be fine for only two replacements:

```
message = message.gsub(/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/) { '<strong>' + $1 + '</strong>' }
message = message.gsub(/\[i\](.*?)\[\/i\]/) { '<em>'     + $1 + '</em>'     }
```

If you try to do it all at once you'll have problems with nesting in something like this:

```
message = 'Where [b]is[/b] pancakes [b]house [i]and[/i] more[/b] stuff?'
```

You'd end up having to use a recursive `gsub` and possibly some lambdas if you wanted to properly handle things like that with a single expression.

There are better things to spend your time on than trying to be clever on something like this.

**Response to comments**: If you have more bb-tags and some smilies to worry about and several messages per page then you should HTMLify each message when you create it. You could store only the HTML version or both HTML and BB-Code versions if you want the BB-Code stuff around for some reason. This way you'd only pay for the HTMLification once per message and producing your big lists would be nearly free.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I use your method, I will be calling hundreds of gsubs on each page render (10 of these BBcodes, plus 15 smilies, + possibly 50 messages per page = 500 gsubs on one page). This is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @bricker: But your approach is doing a lot more matching than you might think, you'll be doing a lot of matches inside your `select` block. If you have a lot of tags and a lot of messages, then you should precompute as the update to my answer suggests.